# Permission denied django uwsgi nginx

Tags: linux, django, nginx, uwsgi

Настроил веб сервер для приложения `Django` используя `nginx`, `uwsgi`.
Все отлично работает, но при добавлении файлов через админку Django выдает ошибку:

> **[Errno 13] Permission denied**: путь к директории медиа файлов(куда
>   Django должен был сохранить файл)  Exception
>   Location: /home/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-
>   packages/django/core/files/storage.py in _save, line 264  Python
>   Executable:   /home/django/venv/bin/uwsgi  Python Version:    3.4.3  Python
>   Path:   ['.',   '',   '/home/django/venv/lib/python3.4',
>   '/home/django/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/home/django/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',   '/usr/lib/python3.4',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/home/django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

При этом через админку можно добавить новые данные в модели если нет медиа. 
Буду признателен за любой совет.

Comment: Очевидно, у пользователя, под которым работает uwsgi, нет прав на запись в `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: а как проверить под каким пользователем работает uwsgi?

Comment: Пользователь по которым идёт запуск **uwsgi** в файле uwsgi.ini -  `uid `

Comment: в общем пробывал по разному ничего не выходит

Comment: добавил пользователя от которого запускался в www-data, добавил www-data привелегии. Отчаявшись сделал chmod 0777 homе. Результат тот же

Comment: Может кто знает где найти логи по этой проблеме. Или где искать дальше. В логах nginx ничего нет

Answer (score 1):

Решение: добавить пользователя, через которого запускается uwsgi.ini файл в группу имеющую доступ к нужным директориям.

```
 usermod -a -G django www-data

-a add( добавить)
-G group(группа)
django - username
www-data - group name
```

В некоторых местах пишут, что название группы должно стоять сначала, но у меня сработал именно такой вариант.